# How to create a local mirror that replicate only the security patches from archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: security, patch, mirrors

Can anyone help me here. I need a local mirror with all the security patches in the Ubuntu mirror. I don't need any other updates due to security constraint. Tried with apt-get but it has only subset of patches. Rsync/wget download the entire mirror which is of 600GB which is not possible. Any other way to do this?

Comment: Pick only `x-security`.